# Microsoft.Build.Task missing

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to use .Net to load reports into SSRS. When I looked up example code they used the Warning class which, after futher research, seems to be in the Microsoft.Build.Task namespace. My problemis that this library doesn't show up when I try to reference it and when I try to add references it doesn't Microsoft.Build doesn't show in the list of .Net references. What am I doing wrong? The compiler does not recognize the class in the following:

Warning[] warnings = Null;

Answer (score 0):

If your using VS 2010 and .net framework 3.5 or 4.0, make sure you have the latest Microsoft.Build.Task, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.

Comment: Where do I find this? It doesn't show up in my list of possible references, I don't see it in .../Common7/IDE, and I can't seem to find a MS download of it. Where should I look to find it in a VS2010 installation and if it is not there where can I download it from?

Comment: Just download the dll if its missing: I just googled it and found this link, not sure if its a good copy of it though...http://dllcentral.com/microsoft.build.tasks.v4.0.dll/1.0/